# How to serialize Xml (from XLSX files) to Json ? C# .NET Json.Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

*I'm processing different kind of Xlsx files. 
These files have multiples possibility of column eg 2 or 6 or even 7 Columns) 

I read the Xml data inside using OpenXml and i would like to generate Json files from each worksheet. 

Actually i'm able to read and to iterate through every worksheet but it seems weird when i try to convert it into Json format using Newtonsoft.Json*

**The Excel files is similare to this** 

Item 1 || Item 2 || Item 3 
V1 || V2 || V3 
V1 || V2 || V3 
V1 || V2 || V3 

 
**But the generated JSON file is similare to this** 

[ 
 [Item 1 ,Item 2 ,Item 3]
 [V1 ,V2 ,V3]
 [V1 ,V2 ,V3]
 [V1 ,V2 ,V3]
]

**And i would like to format it like this**

{ 
 {"Item 1":"V1" ,"Item 2":"V2" ,"Item 3":"V3"}
 {"Item 1":"V1" ,"Item 2":"V2" ,"Item 3":"V3"}
 {"Item 1":"V1" ,"Item 2":"V2" ,"Item 3":"V3"}
 }

Here is my code :

using (SpreadsheetDocument excelDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file, false))
            {
                var documentBody = excelDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook;

```
            var sheets = documentBody.Sheets.Cast<Sheet>().ToList();
            sheets.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(String.Format("RelationshipId:{0}\n SheetName:{1}\n SheetId:{2}", x.Id.Value, x.Name.Value, x.SheetId.Value)));

            SharedStringTablePart sstpart = excelDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
            SharedStringTable sst = sstpart.SharedStringTable;

            Console.WriteLine("Worksheet count = {0}", documentBody.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.Count());

            foreach (var worksheetPart in documentBody.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts)
            {

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet sheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

                var cells = sheet.Descendants<Cell>();
                var rows = sheet.Descendants<Row>();

                Console.WriteLine("Row count = {0}", rows.LongCount());
                Console.WriteLine("Cell count = {0}", cells.LongCount());
                var list = new List<string[]>();
                foreach (Row row in rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Row number: {0}", row.RowIndex);
                    list.Add(row.Elements<Cell>().Select(x => x.InnerText).ToArray());
                    foreach (Cell c in row.Elements<Cell>())
                    {
                        if (c.CellValue != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Cell contents: {0}", c.CellValue.Text);

                        }
                    }
                }
                var i = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case I recommend to use List of ExpandoObject instead of List of string[].
It's a dynamic object generated as a IDictionnary

```
var list = new List<ExpandoObject>();
var expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
var dict = (IDictionary<string, Object>)expandoObject;
dict.Add("NewProp", "prop value");
dict.Add("SecondProp", 58);
list.add(expandoObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert an XML node contained in string xml into a JSON string

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

To convert JSON text contained in string json into an XML node

```
 XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
```

Documentation here: [Click Here for Documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm)

OR Try this below Code there i have used dictionary

```
class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    var xml = 
    @"<Columns>
      <Column Name=""key1"" DataType=""Boolean"">True</Column>
      <Column Name=""key2"" DataType=""String"">Hello World</Column>
      <Column Name=""key3"" DataType=""Integer"">999</Column>
    </Columns>";
    var dic = XDocument
        .Parse(xml)
        .Descendants("Column")
        .ToDictionary(
            c => c.Attribute("Name").Value, 
            c => c.Value
        );
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dic);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

}

Comment: A json serialization of a dictionnary give { "key": "property", "Value": objectValue } cause of the KeyValuePair object